# Invoke .cls without pausing in Windbg

Tags: windbg

Is there a way to clear the WinDbg output, without pausing it first?

Right now I had to pause WinDbg then invoke `.cls` manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at edit menu
you should see a clear command history command

edit gif attached

[image]